# tiles2 definition not working with ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tiles, tiles2, url-mapping

I'm using ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping to avoid explicitly mapping URLs to controllers, and so far it works fine. I have a link in index.jsp to welcome.html, which is properly mapped to welcomeController, which contains the following:

```
    setCommandClass(User.class);
    setCommandName("user");
    setSuccessView("homeView");
    setFormView("welcomeView");
```

The problem is that when I try to add a tile in tiles.xml definition with that URL like this:

```
<definition name="welcome" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome!"/>
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/welcomeView.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

The only tiles bean i declared within dispatcher-servlet.xml is:

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
      <property name="definitions">
          <list>
              <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
          </list>
      </property>
</bean>
```

I've tried many permutations with the tiles.xml file so far with no success. The view is loaded correctly, i get no errors in console, but tiles is nowhere to be seen.
What am i missing?

Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may not have a `ViewResolver` for tiles configured.  From the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-tiles)

```
To be able to use the views you have to have a ViewResolver 
just as with any other view technology used with Spring.
```

You can choose between `UrlBasedViewResolver` and `ResourceBundleViewResolver`.

It looks like currently it is resolving the view name (`welcomeView`) to the corresponding jsp (`welcomeView.jsp`) and thus you are not getting the tiles.

Answer (score 0):

I have view resolver declared as follows

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp"
      p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"
/>
```